# convertBaseToScreen method now deprecated

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

My old code uses convertBaseToScreen which is now deprecated. Although I don't use this code in my app anymore due to removal of feature, I was wondering to main old code should I plan to bring this feature back, Is there anyway I can get helpful folks here to help change the code?

```
- (void) updateAdWindow
{
    NSPoint origin = [window convertBaseToScreen:NSMakePoint( (window.frame.size.width - adWindow.frame.size.width)/2, 0)];
    origin.y -= adWindow.frame.size.height;

    if( closed )
        [adWindow setFrame:NSMakeRect(origin.x, origin.y, WIN_SIZE_WIDTH, 0) display:TRUE];
    else
        [adWindow setFrame:NSMakeRect(origin.x, origin.y, adWindow.frame.size.width, adWindow.frame.size.height) display:TRUE];
}
```

I cannot test this unfortunately and the replacement new method seem very different from the old one. How to convert?

Comment: Would convertPointToBacking or convertPoint: toView: work?

Comment: I am not too sure, since I cannot test it out I was hoping someone who might have done this help with this code.

Answer (score 3):

The NSWindow method:  convertRectToScreen: does not have a compatible signature with convertBaseToScreen: so it may be helpful to use the following NSWindow category method:

```
@implementation NSWindow (ExileTriage)

- (NSPoint) convertPointToScreen:(NSPoint)point
{
    NSRect convertRect = [self convertRectToScreen:NSMakeRect(point.x, point.y, 0.0, 0.0)];
    return NSMakePoint(convertRect.origin.x, convertRect.origin.y);
}

@end
```

Comment: Is this implementation equivalent to the one that Apple offers starting with 10.12 and which has the exact same name and signature?

Answer (score 0):

Apple's documentation says:

> Use convertRectToScreen: instead.

Convert window.frame and use the result to calculate origin.